# Spring boot - app.groovy - fails to run: The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start, while 8080 is listening

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9

I'm setting up a stack on my home laptop on Ubuntu 18.04.
So far Tomcat9 and Spring CLI v2.1.2 are installed. I'm trying to test whether the current install is so far working.

According to the official Spring install [tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-installing-spring-boot.html), when all done the app.groovy can be run.

app.groovy contains the following code as per the above-linked page:

```
    @RestController
    class ThisWillActuallyRun {

        @RequestMapping("/")
        String home() {
            "Hello, World!"
        }

    }
```

I run the app with the following command from the terminal:

```
    spring run app.groovy
```

The output is the following:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (jar:file:/opt/spring/spring-2.1.2.RELEASE/lib/spring-boot-cli-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/groovy-2.5.5.jar!/) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.2.RELEASE)

2019-01-30 08:47:30.351  INFO 18651 --- [       runner-0] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application on LS-LINUX with PID 18651 (started by ls in /home/ls/Documents)
2019-01-30 08:47:30.376  INFO 18651 --- [       runner-0] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-30 08:47:33.196  INFO 18651 --- [       runner-0] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-01-30 08:47:33.317  INFO 18651 --- [       runner-0] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-01-30 08:47:33.318  INFO 18651 --- [       runner-0] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
2019-01-30 08:47:33.340  INFO 18651 --- [       runner-0] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib]
2019-01-30 08:47:33.434  INFO 18651 --- [       runner-0] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader  : Unknown class loader [org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.ExtendedGroovyClassLoader$DefaultScopeParentClassLoader@163cf7a3] of class [class org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.ExtendedGroovyClassLoader$DefaultScopeParentClassLoader]
2019-01-30 08:47:33.517  INFO 18651 --- [       runner-0] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-01-30 08:47:33.518  INFO 18651 --- [       runner-0] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2617 ms
2019-01-30 08:47:34.014  INFO 18651 --- [       runner-0] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-01-30 08:47:34.886 ERROR 18651 --- [       runner-0] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase   : Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1004) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:226) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:259) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) [spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.app.SpringApplicationLauncher.launch(SpringApplicationLauncher.java:69) [classes!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.SpringApplicationRunner$RunThread.run(SpringApplicationRunner.java:173) [classes!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:225) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:236) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1085) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:568) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1001) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    ... 17 common frames omitted

2019-01-30 08:47:34.896  INFO 18651 --- [       runner-0] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-01-30 08:47:34.912  INFO 18651 --- [       runner-0] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-01-30 08:47:34.919 ERROR 18651 --- [       runner-0] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2019-01-30 08:47:34.920 ERROR 18651 --- [       runner-0] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2019-01-30 08:47:34.923  INFO 18651 --- [       runner-0] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.app.SpringApplicationLauncher.launch(SpringApplicationLauncher.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.SpringApplicationRunner$RunThread.run(SpringApplicationRunner.java:173)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.ConnectorStartFailedException: Connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.checkConnectorHasStarted(TomcatWebServer.java:232)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.checkThatConnectorsHaveStarted(TomcatWebServer.java:224)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    ... 6 more
```

I've read at several sources, that the port 8080 may be occupied by another running app. I tried to find out what the problem might be. I used two commands to check the usage of port 8080.

1.

```
    sudo netstat -plnt | grep ':8080'
```

Answers:

```
    tcp6       0      0 :::8080    :::*      LISTEN  21659/java
```

2.

```
    sudo lsof -i:8080
```

Answers:

```
    COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
    java    21659 tomcat   41u  IPv6 239756      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

When I open up http://127.0.0.1:8080/ or http://localhost:8080/
I get the tomcat welcome page with the text showing the successful install of tomcat.
"f you're seeing this, you've successfully installed Tomcat. Congratulations!"

Can you please advice what I'm doing wrong and what the solution might be?

Comment: Can you kill the running process using the PID and restart the spring appliction? `kill -9 21659`

Comment: I killed the process and then tried to re-run the spring app. I got the same error.

Comment: 1) Kill process. 2) Check that nothing is listening on port. 3) Start application only 4) Crashes?

Comment: I did the steps you described. Nothing was listening on port 8080 before I started the app. I have the same negative result.

Comment: Spring Boot application uses embedded tomcat and starts it when you run your application. You can start your application on 8080 port as you have installed Tomcat server, that usually is used for Spring MVC (not spring boot) projects. In order to start your Spring Boot application you need to kill Tomcat server firstly or simply change server.port property to another from 8080

Comment: Stopping tomcat and then launching the app worked well. Thanks Bohdan for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I also received this type of error in spring boot suite and it  got resolved,
the issue was because the tomcat was already running on the machine , in order to resolve the issue you should stop the server first then try to run that project again..